# Image extension JPG or PNG

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I wrote a simple Python program and its working fine.

Basically what I wrote that enter image URL and its save to the computer but I want to add one more extra thing that couldn't fix it. I want to avoid error if image URL don't have Jpg or PNG format. How Should i do that?

Code is below:

```
import requests

def download():
    url = input("Enter Image URL >> ")
    response = requests.get(url)
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    if file_name == "jpg":

        with open(file_name, "wb") as saveImg:
            if saveImg.write(response.content):
                print("[+] Download Complete")
            else:
                print("[-] Download Failed.")
    else:
        print("Failed")            


download()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
if file_name == "jpg":
```

[You want](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
import os

_, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
if ext == "jpg":
```

or perhaps:

```
if ext in ("jpg", "png"):
```

or

```
if ext.lower() in ("jpg", "png"):
```

If you don't import `os`, you might still be able to get away with something like `if file_name.endswith(".jpg")`.

Comment: Hello @J_H. Thanks for your answer. I'm able to apply ```if file_name.endswith(".jpg")``` this one and working properly but failed to apply above lines ```import os```. Here is the updated code. please  have a look >>> http://prntscr.com/si9bjo

Comment: Note that the `_` underscore in `_, ext = ...` just says we're not interested in that particular value. We could capture the basename using `base, ext = ...` if desired. Be sure to `print(ext, base)` when debugging it. I saw you use `with open(ext, "wb")` -- you would probably prefer `with open(file_name, "wb")` there. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Answer (score 2):

**updated code >>>**

```
import requests
import os.path

def download():
    url = input("Enter Image URL >> ")
    response = requests.get(url)

    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    _, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)

    if ext in (".jpg", ".png"):

        with open(file_name, "wb") as saveImg:
            if saveImg.write(response.content):
                print("[+] Download Complete")
            else:
                print("[-] Download Failed.")
    else:
        print("[-] Please Enter Valid Image URL.")            


download()
```

Comment: why we use _,? Please help me to understand. Thank you.

Comment: You don't care about the variable, that's the naming convention for that case